# predicted probability plot with robust errors for logit model

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a predicted probability plot for a logit model, using clustered robust standard errors. Supposedly the margins package should let you do this, using cplot(), but there seems to be a bug, such that cplot() doesn't recognize the optional vcov input. Below is a minimum working example. Does anyone know how to fix the bug or do this another way?

```
require("margins")
require("sandwich")

##Generating random numbers
set.seed(10)
y<-factor(rbinom(n=1000,size=1,prob=.5))
x <- rnorm(n=1000, mean=100,sd=1)
z<- rbinom(n=1000,size=3,prob=.5)
#creating a "dataset"
dta<-data.frame(x,y,z)

##Basic logit model
model <-glm(y~x,family="binomial"(link="logit"),data=dta)

##Creating variance-covariance matrix, clustered by z
vcov <- vcovCL(model, cluster=z)

##Making a plot
cplot(model,"x",vcov=vcov,what="prediction")

#can see below that vcov has no effect (if not obvious from plot)
print(cplot(model,"x",vcov=vcov,what="prediction",draw=FALSE))
print(cplot(model,"x",what="prediction",draw=FALSE))
```

Comment: Looking at the `margins:::cplot.glm` function, the `vcov` is only used when `what="effect"`, not `what="prediction"`.

Comment: Well that explains why it isn't working! Thanks. Do you happen to know of an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Honestly i don't know exactly what "this" is in your case. If you described the calculation you you want to perform (give the formula), we might be able to translate that to R code. Otherwise maybe consult a statisctican over at [stats.se].

Comment: By "this" I mean, how could I make a predicted probability plot that shows robust clustered standard errors for a logit model.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
# Predict values
pred.dta <- ggeffects::ggpredict(
      model=model,
      terms="x [all]", 
      vcov.fun="vcovCL",
      vcov.type="HC1",
      vcov.args=list(cluster=z) 
      )    
# Plot predictions
ggplot2::ggplot(data=pred.dta, 
                ggplot2::aes(x=x, y=predicted))+
ggplot2::geom_line()+
ggplot2::geom_errorbar(ggplot2::aes(ymin=conf.low, ymax=conf.high), width=.1)
```

For comparison, this is the same code but without the clustered errors:

```
# Predict values
pred.dta <- ggeffects::ggpredict(
      model=model,
      terms="x [all]" )
      
# Plot predictions
ggplot2::ggplot(data=pred.dta, 
                ggplot2::aes(x=x, y=predicted))+
ggplot2::geom_line()+
ggplot2::geom_errorbar(ggplot2::aes(ymin=conf.low, ymax=conf.high), width=.1)
```